# How to append the first line at the end of each line of a file with Sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to append the first line of a file at the end of each line with a single `sed` command:

Example:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

should become:

```
line 1 line 1
line 2 line 1
line 3 line 1
line 4 line 1
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
sed -e '1h;G;s/\n/ /' <file
```

Comment: @user3576105 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.